# How to use the `Java Options` in jenkins ant build tool to set ANT_OPTS

Tags: java, ant, hudson, jenkins

I have a problem with a `junit` ant build, i'm getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error.

I'm trying to set `ANT_OPTS` to be `ANT_OPTS='-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m'` in the build `Java Options` to increase the heap size ant build tool.
[image]

But i get an error each time i run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: ANT_OPTS=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m.  Program will exit.
```

A syntax error ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the JAVA OPTIONS as `-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` only without the `ANT_OPTS=`

Answer (score 2):

Also, u can add memory option in the build file also, like `memoryInitialSize="256m" memoryMaximumSize="512m"`. this will help. as i am using the same, and it caused no problem till now.

Comment: i prefer not to change the build.xml file itself, as other CI use it as well and i don't want to break anything.

Comment: @Michael :  are you building your application using hudson?? if yes, then there is no need to define such instead In hudson there is a text box with label `Java Option`, directly add the java option u want to add `-Xms512M -Xmx1024M`, this will help